# Magento EXPORT configurable products

Tags: magento, csv, export, magento-1.7

I need to import a .csv file with configurable products.

In order to do so, you need to add 2 new columns to the original file created by Magento: `associated` and `configurable_attributes`. I cannot find any examples that show how this is done - So how I can create and fill these columns?

It is impossible to do it manually in this instance, because I have +20k products. Can I force Magento to create these columns when exporting the `.csv` file? Can I use some custom xml for Advanced Dataflow profile?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a good bit of research on this for a client that I had. It turns out that importing configurable products in Magento is just plain nasty. The client that I was working for was actually coming from another ecommerce system, so there was much more to do than just those two columns. What I did was read the csv file and add the columns in a program. I wrote it in C# with the FileHelpers library to read the csv and just manually wrote the csv back with a `StreamReader` and a couple `foreach` loops. It really isn't too much code to write if you're familiar with any programming language.

I will say that you'll only be able to make these columns if there is a specific pattern to follow with what configurable attribute is being associated with a product, or if they are all the same; otherwise, there is no way to be able to know what attributes to associate with each product. To this extent, I believe you could add the columns to a DataFlow export in Magento, but the columns would just be blank.

Comment: the fun part is that Magento can't even import its own exports. what a nightmare!

Comment: agreed, this is frustrating. I've added another answer to this topic to share the tool which handles this (preserving the format for import and export), hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/). It uses direct SQL calls, can handle imports of both configurable and bundled products, and greatly simplifies the import process overall.

Like @danielu13 points out, your other option is to call the Magento API from a script. There's a lot the Magento importer can't do.

As far as I know, Magento doesn't do the kind of export you want. There are extensions that will do this kind of export for you, or you could write your own script. You would need to loop through all of your products, get the type of each with `$product->getTypeId()`, and then get the associated simple skus with

```
$product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts()
```

when `getTypeId` returns `'configurable'` or

```
$product->getTypeInstance(true)
    ->getSelectionsCollection($_typeInstance->getOptionsIds($product), $product)
```

when `getTypeId` returns `'bundle'`.

It's ugly, but that's Magento for you.

Comment: I've tried with Magmi and it also needs new columns that magento doesn't export by default. it needs the "configurable_attributes" column and a "simples_skus" one (because for unknown reasons the sku auto match doesn't work).. so it's pretty much the same, unfortunately.

Comment: Check the edits above. Magento doesn't do what you want out of the box, so you'll need to get an extension or write a script.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Indeed there is no possibility to Export this kind of data from Magento DB into your CSV and then import it back. It won't work because the formats are different. So people usually have to post-process their exported data to make it compatible with Import function.

However for those who is considering paid solutions [this](http://productuploader.magelynx.com) could be a good tool. It provides possibility to export your configurable product while keeping the format compatible for the back process (importing).

Say for example you have configurable product with color/size variants. In such case, you need to
1) add following headers.
**sku, name, type, color, size, simples_skus, configurable_attributes, super_attribute_pricing**

2) export your configurable product and attached simple products into the spreadsheet. It will populate the values:
for the configurable product it will populate columns **simples_skus, configurable_attributes, super_attribute_pricing**
for the simple products it will populate columns "color" and "size".

Once you try to import it back - it's going to work flawlessly.

This format of data is also supported by MAGMI and inherited from there as the tool I'm referring to is basically a MAGMI integration into Magento backend with some additinal extended functionality (like possibility to export products into the spreadsheet).